# Where to get more detailed jQuery syntax other than the official website?

Tags: jquery, documentation

I know it sounds stupid but I found the official jQuery website's description of some syntaxes are not very detailed.

For instance, I came across some codes on stackoverflow like this:

```
animate({width:'toggle'}, 1000)
```

On https://api.jquery.com/animate/, I don't see any explanation of this kind of usage (in the section of "options", I don't see anything similar to "{width:toggle}"). So is there any other place I can get more detailed descriptions of jQuery syntaxes? Or there is just something I missed on the official page?

Comment: I don't see your problem. This exact syntax is outlined in the documentation and even given an example.

Comment: Open the page you linked and do a search for the word "toggle".  It's clearly explained.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's answered in a link the OP posted themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery documentations is as follows:

`.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

In your example `properties` === {width: 'toggle'}, which is just a [Plain Object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) and the duration is 1000 miliseconds.  The brackets indicate that the values are optional, and easing and complete are omitted.